# The landscape and portrait orientation in android

Tags: android

I set the activity landscape orientation compulsory. It locks the screen and then unlock screen in activity.

But now activity screen changed from portrait to landscape.

That is to say after lock the screen it changes to portrait orientation from landscape.

How to keep landscape all the time after I set the activity landscape orientation compulsory? Even it is locked screen.

Comment: To lock in a particular orientation, you must specify it in the manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

in AndroidMainfest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".path.to.Activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
```